# Upgrade extension version

Tags: magento2

Is their any way we can upgrade extension version using composer.lock file ?
I have upgraded version in local dev environment but older version of modules in staging.

i am trying to make same version in staging for the modules.

I have tried

```
sudo composer require klarna/m2-payments:* --update-with-dependencies
```

but it downloads other modules too.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you install your module via composer before, just run `composer require <module-name> --no-update`, then `composer update` to update the extension version.

Comment: composer update will update all extension version.